# What is the difference between these two neural network structures?

Tags: python, pytorch

first using nn.Parameter

```
class ModelOne(nn.Module):
  def __init__(self):
    super().__init__()
    self.weights = nn.Parameter(torch.randn(300, 10))
    self.bias = nn.Parameter(torch.zeros(10))
  def forward(self, x):
    return x @ self.weights + self.bias
```

when I do

```
mo = ModelOne()
[len(param) for param in mo.parameters()]
```

it gives
[300, 10]

second using nn.Linear

```
class ModelTwo(nn.Module):
  def __init__(self):
    super().__init__()
    self.linear = nn.Linear(300, 10)

  def forward(self, x):
    return self.linear(x)
```

same thing here gives
[10, 10]

Answer (score 3):

The difference lies in how [`nn.Linear`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/_modules/torch/nn/modules/linear.html) initializes weights and bias:

```
class Linear(Module):

    def __init__(self, in_features, out_features, bias=True):
        super(Linear, self).__init__()
        self.in_features = in_features
        self.out_features = out_features
        self.weight = Parameter(torch.Tensor(out_features, in_features))
        if bias:
            self.bias = Parameter(torch.Tensor(out_features))
        ...
```

So, when you write `nn.Linear(300, 10)` the weight is (10, 300) and bias is (10). But, in the ModelOne, weights has dimension (300, 10).

You can confirm it using

```
for name, param in mo.named_parameters():
    print(name, param.shape)
```

*The output in ModelOne:*

weights torch.Size([300, 10])
bias torch.Size([10])

*In ModelTwo:*

linear.weight torch.Size([10, 300])
linear.bias torch.Size([10])

---

Now, the reason you're getting [300, 10] in first case and [10, 10] in second case is because if you print the length of a 2d Tensor, then it'll only give its first dimension i.e.

```
a = torch.Tensor(10, 300)
b = torch.Tensor(10)
print(len(a), len(b))
```

(10, 10)